# How to print first element from dropdown list on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function :

```
function LoadRegions() {
    var region = $('#RegionID');


    var url = "/Account/GetRegions";
    $.getJSON(url, { countryId: $('#CountryID').val() }, function (response) {
        // clear and add default (null) option 

        //region.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));



        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            region.append($('<option></option>').val(response[i].Id).text(response[i].Name));
        }

    });
}
```

When user choose countrie i call this function but i want to display on start first element from that list...
With this line i get "Please select" but i want first element from list:

```
  region.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
```

If i comment this line i get blank...any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem could have been the issues with chaining. See the documentation for **[end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/)**.

The `empty()` and `append()` were being done on the same chain. This can sometimes cause issues because of the chaining algorithm. The **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/end/)** has good description of the issue.

This can fix your problem.

```
$.getJSON(url, {
    countryId: $('#CountryID').val()
}, function(response) {
    // clear and add default (null) option 
    region
        .empty()
        .end()
        .append($('<option>', {
            value: '',
            text: 'Please select'
        }));
    $.each(response, function(key, tocken) {
        region.append($('<option>', {
            value: tocken["Id"],
            text: tocken["Name"]
        }));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the attribute `selected` in the option tag in order to set the option as selected. To do this, you need to modify your for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if(i==0)
        region.append($('<option selected></option>').val(response[i].Id).text(response[i].Name));
    else
        region.append($('<option></option>').val(response[i].Id).text(response[i].Name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s_string = '<option>Select Value </option>';

for () // your for loop 
{
  s_string+=''; //your option tag code (appned fetch data in same variable and appned that variable after for loop end)
}

// appand s_string variable to your destination id or class (append)
```